# Trying to implement a variable Int into a System.out.format

Tags: java, system.out

I'm focusing on these lines of my code right here:

```
System.out.println() ;
System.out.println("Item\tQuantity\tPrice\t    Total") ;

for (int i = 0; i < s_nextGame; i++) {
    result = s_quantity[i]*s_price[i] ;

    System.out.format("%11d\t%9.3f\t%11f\n", s_quantity[i],
        s_price[i], result) ;
```

I need to implement an int variable I declared "called s_name" but when I add it to the format output statement, I get this:

```
Item    Quantity        Price       Total
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2748)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2702)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at Inventory.printInventory(Inventory.java:85)
    at Inventory.main(Inventory.java:111)
```

and when I dont it kinda works and instead prints this:

```
Item    Quantity        Price       Total
      1        29.990         29.990000
      1        39.990         39.990000
      1        19.990         19.990000
      2        14.990         29.980000
Total = 119.950
```

As you can see, nothing pops up for the "items" part of it. So, my question is, how do I add s_name to the output statement?

Thanks in advance.

I declared s_name at the top of the code:
private static int[] s_name = new int[s_maxGames] ;

I also tried %s string format and this is the output:

```
Item    Quantity        Price       Total
[I@71881149               1        29.990         29.990000
[I@71881149               1        39.990         39.990000
[I@71881149               1        19.990         19.990000
[I@71881149               2        14.990         29.980000
Total = 119.950
```

please excuse the off centering its still a work in progress

here is my code:

```
import java.io.File ;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException ;
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class Inventory {

  private static int s_maxGames = 10 ;

  private static int[] s_name = new int[s_maxGames] ;

  private static int[] s_quantity = new int[s_maxGames] ;

  private static double[] s_price = new double[s_maxGames] ;

  private static int s_nextGame = 0 ;

  public static void loadInventory(String fileName)
    throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    if ( (fileName != null) && (!fileName.equals("")) ) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName)) ;
      String newLine = null ;

  while (input.hasNextLine() && s_nextGame < s_maxGames) {


    if (input.hasNext()) {
        String name = input.next() ;
    } else {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Expected a name in column 1 of line "
            + (s_nextGame+1) + " (not \"" + input.next() + "\").");
        System.exit(2);
    }


    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        s_quantity[s_nextGame] = input.nextInt() ;
    } else {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Expected a int in column 2 of line "
            + (s_nextGame+1) + " (not \"" + input.next() + "\").");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        s_price[s_nextGame] = input.nextDouble() ;
    } else {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Expected a double in column 3 of line "
            + (s_nextGame+1) + " (not \"" + input.next() + "\").");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    newLine = input.nextLine() ;

    s_nextGame += 1 ;
  }
}

if (s_nextGame == 0) {
  System.out.println("WARNING: There are NO items on the list.") ;
}

return ;
  }



  public static void printInventory()
  {
    double result ;

System.out.println() ;
System.out.println("Item\tQuantity\tPrice\t    Total") ;

for (int i = 0; i < s_nextGame; i++) {
    result = s_quantity[i]*s_price[i] ;

    System.out.format("%s\t%11d\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\n", s_name[i], s_quantity[i],
        s_price[i], result) ;
}

return ;
}

public static double calculateTotalValue()
{
double total = 0.0 ;

for (int i = 0; i < s_nextGame; i++) {
  total = s_quantity[i]*s_price[i] + total ;
}

return total ;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
{
if (args.length != 1) {
  System.err.println("Usage: java Inventory <input file name>") ;
  System.exit(1) ;
}

loadInventory(args[0]) ;
printInventory() ;
System.out.format("Total = %6.3f\n", calculateTotalValue()) ;

return ;
}
}}
```

when I run

```
 System.out.format("%s\t%11d\t%9.3f\t%11f\n", s_name[i], s_quantity[i],
    s_price[i], result) ;
```

I get:

```
 Item    Quantity        Price       Total
 0                 1         29.99             29.99
 0                 1         39.99             39.99
 0                 1         19.99             19.99
 0                 2         14.99             29.98
 Total = 119.950
```

and replacing %s with %d I get the exact same output

my txt file I am using, games.txt looks like this

```
 SuperKaup 1 29.99
 Survivor 1 39.99
 RyansMaze 1 19.99
 TeacherSimulator 2 14.99
```

Answer (score 3):

This error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I
```

Suggests that you appear to be trying to convert an array of int, `[I`, into an int, which is not legal. Are you using `s_name` where you should be using `s_name[i]`? For more help, please show the actual code that's not working and tell more details.

Also, I would also guess that a name variable would hold a String and thus would need to use the `%s` format specifier.

---

Regarding your latest code post:

```
System.out.format("%s\t%11d\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\n", 
       s_name[i], s_quantity[i], s_price[i], result);
```

What happens when you run this?

What about when you run this?

```
System.out.format("%d\t%11d\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\n", 
       s_name[i], s_quantity[i], s_price[i], result);
```

---

**Edit 2**

OK your text file shows a String as the first token on each line. Thus you should have an array of String, not ints for the name. You need to rethink your logic.

---

**Edit 3**
Suggestions:

- If this were my project, I'd create one Scanner object initialized with the File, say called fileScanner, and use it to read each line of the file, as long as `while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())` is true. I'd store the line in a String variable.
- Inside that while loop, I'd create another Scanner object, say called lineScanner, that was initialized with the String, line, that was just created.
- I'd extract my tokens from the line using lineScanner.
- And I'd fill my arrays with data. Later you'd probably create a class to hold the data all together in one object, but for now, fill your parallel arrays.
- Then at the end of the while loop, I'd close my lineScanner object so to release system resources.
- The key here is to simplify your code and your logic so it is easier to understand and debug.
- Again your name array (I'd call it names) would be an array of String. I'm pretty sure that you know how to declare and initialize an array of String since you've done it for ints.

Comment: Ok, I did that but instead of names that appear, just a bunch of zeros appear. Would you like my entire code?

Comment: @GEARZ: see edit to answer. Also, what does your data file look like?

Comment: @GEARZ: Please don't try to edit my answer  as that invalidates it. Instead please  edit **your question**, and then notify me in comment about your edit.

Comment: Ok so replacing %s with %d doesnt change the output I posted

Comment: @GEARZ: see edit. You're doing it wrong. You should be using an array of String to hold String data. How can "SuperKaup" be represented as an int? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Ok, so when I declare s_name, how do I declare it as a string instead?

Comment: @GEARZ: Are you asking how to declare an array of String? Really?

Comment: Yea. I mean like obviously I cant change int to string or something. Im a little new to Java programming so please bear with me.

Comment: Use `List`S instead; a list of `String` is `List<String> s_name = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: @GEARZ: see **Edit 3** for suggestions. I'd re-write the whole thing since your code is a bit convoluted and hard to change or improve.

Comment: Im trying to declare the String as a private static otherwise I cant put it to System.out.format. will that work?

Answer (score 1):

s_name is defined as an array of int. You should use %d instead of %s.

```
 int[] s_name = new int[s_maxGames];
 System.out.format("%d\t%11d\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\n", s_name[i], s_quantity[i],
    s_price[i], result) ;
```

All items are displayed as 0 because s_name is never set in the code. 0 is the default value of integers. You should do something like this.

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    // String name = input.next() ;
    s_name[s_nextGame] = input.nextInt();
} else {
    System.err.println("ERROR: Expected a name in column 1 of line "
        + (s_nextGame+1) + " (not \"" + input.next() + "\").");
    System.exit(2);
}
```

Comment: All s_name are set to 0 because s_name[i] are never set in your code. 0 is the default value for int.

Comment: ok so in my games.txt file above, the 0's are supposed to be the names in the file. So how do I read them in as names instead of 0's?

Comment: replace String name = input.next() by s_name[s_nextGame] = input.next()

Comment: I tried to change it but it says an "int" is required after input.next() probably because of the declaration at the top. What should I change it to?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Hovercraft Full Of Eels explained, you have some problems with your logic. You seem confused as to whether `s_name` should be an array of `int` or `String`, so I'm going to assume it doesn't matter. A `String` would make more sense.

Since you're new to Java, you should know that there is a `List` object that is much more suited for this kind of thing (less programming required to do obvious tasks such as iterating). I would recommend changing all of your arrays to `List`, unless you're trying to optimise your code in some way (which I doubt you are at this point in time).

`s_name` as a `List` of `String` can be declared like so:

```
List<String> s_name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can read the API documentation for `List` here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: I tried to Implement that exactly and I got an error: Inventory.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  List <String> s_name = new ArrayList<String>() ;
  ^
  symbol:   class List
  location: class Inventory
Inventory.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  List <String> s_name = new ArrayList<String>() ;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class Inventory
Inventory.java:85: error: non-static variable s_name cannot be referenced from a static context
        System.out.format("%s\t%11d\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\n",  s_name, s_quantity[i],

Comment: Its not allowing me to declare s_name like that

Comment: @GEARZ: you're likely not importing the `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`. 1+ to this decent answer.

Comment: @ GEARZ: 1. You can't access a non static member from a static context
2. You have a space between `List` and `<String>` in your example

Comment: While it allowed me to compile List<String> s_name = new ArrayList<String>() ; this time, it still says what wulfgar said about not being able to access a non static to a static context. So how do I fix this?

Comment: @GEARZ: Depending on your design, either make `s_name` static like the method you're accessing it from, or make neither static and instantiate your class.

Comment: I made it static but the output for the names is still not working. its just boxes that looks like this [] why is the scanner not reading them into words?

Comment: @GEARZ: You'll have to do some Googling :), it's better to learn rather than ask so many questions.

Comment: I already tried and I'm getting impatient because the only reason I joined this site is because my new programming professor is not helpful and doesnt read her email until 11 pm at night and this assignment is due by midnight so please, if you can help me anymore I would be very happy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what some of your other code looks like but I think you probably want your System.out line to look something like:

```
    System.out.format("%s %11d\t%9.2f\t%11.2f\n", s_name[i], s_quantity[i], s_price[i], result)
```

I also added .2 to both of your float format specifiers (%f) since you are dealing with money and probably only want to round to 2 decimal places...

Also seems like your s_name array should be declared as an array of strings, not ints. But alas, as the other poster has suggested, you have not shown us this part of the code.

Comment: How do I declare it as a string instead of an int?